# how to decrease the height between paragraphs i.e <p> </p> in JSP

Tags: height, paragraph

I got 4 paragraphs like

abcd

efgh

ijkl

mnop

Here is the code:

```
    <p style="line-height: 2"> <label><font color="red">*</font>Alamat :</label> 
${actionBean.deposit.alamat1} <p style="line-height: 1"> <label>&nbsp;</label> 
${actionBean.deposit.alamat2} </p> <p style="line-height: 1"> <label>&nbsp;</label>
 ${actionBean.deposit.alamat3} </p>
```

the size between the paragraphs is too big. I use the line-height attribute but its not workin properly....Please suggest me a good option.

```
                           Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: post your HTML code here too.

Comment: <p style="line-height: 2">
                    <label><font color="red">*</font>Alamat :</label>
                        ${actionBean.deposit.alamat1}
                <p style="line-height: 1">
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    ${actionBean.deposit.alamat2}
                </p>
                <p style="line-height: 1">
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    ${actionBean.deposit.alamat3}
                </p>